# Change menu (nav) items to uppercase in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently going through Wordpress tutorials.

The pages that I have created here are all in Capatalized case (e.g. About us). During run-time I want them to automatically convert to upper-case (i.e. ABOUT US) instead of changing the page titles through the dashboard.

I am aware about the php's **strtoupper()** method however not sure where to apply this so that it dynamically changes the page titles to upper-case in the nav menu.

CODE in **header.php**:

```html
<!-- Nav Menu -->
<nav class="site-nav clearfix">
  <?php
$args = array(
'theme_location' => 'primary'
);

wp_nav_menu( $args ); enter code here
?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code in the stylesheet should work:

```
nav.site-nav li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `text-transform: uppercase;` :)

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy true - I mixed up the two terms. Thank you for pointing that out, I changed it!

Comment: @Johannes, Yes. Like a Boss. ;-)
Thanks buddy.